# The beginning of Judaism

Tags: europe, judaism

Did Moses Maimonides (1135-1204), also known as Rambam, write the 5 books of Moses, known in Christianity as the Pentateuch?

Comment: The problem I have with closing this is that, while it might indeed be on the basic side, the misconception in the question is not only very widespread, but in fact an article of faith for a hefty percentage of the world (including a *majority* of the population of my US state).

Comment: The [earliest manuscripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint_manuscripts#List_of_manuscripts) of the [Greek Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint) date to the fourth century AD, and [those](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hebrew_Bible_manuscripts#Masoretic_(7th–10th_century)) of the [Masoretic text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_Text) to at least a whole century or more, before Maimonides' birth.

Answer (score 10):

No: he just had the same name.

The "five books of Moses" are so called because they were believed to have been written by the Moses whose life is described within them. They are actually known in Hebrew as the *chumash* (which means a set of five) or as the Torah ("instruction"), while the word Pentateuch (also, a set of five) comes from Greek They have existed for well over two thousand years, and are found amongst the Dead Sea Scrolls. [Here is the Wikipedia article on this text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torah).

Moses Maimonides, as you note, lived less than one thousand years ago. Maimonides, in Greek, means "son of Maimon". His Hebrew denotation (Rabbi Moshe ben Maimon) is often abbreviated as Rambam. He wrote a great many texts, but most famous amongst them is his codification of all Jewish law: a fourteen-volume opus called *Mishne Torah*. [Here is the Wikipedia article on Maimonides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides).